# Order Parenthesised String into into Map

Tags: apex

So I am trying to take the below string

```
(what(so(ever)(never))(in(tarnation)))
```

into the following structure

```
{
    "str": "what",
    "children": [
        {
            "str": "so",
            "children": [
                {
                    "str": "ever"
                },
                {
                    "str": "never"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "str": "in",
            "children": [
                {
                    "str": "tarnation"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Based upon the below class

```
public class Section{

    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String str;
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Section> children;
    
}
```

I am trying to make this work and have been looking at regex using "([\w\d\s]*)" but the issue is keeping them parented to each other when going child out I have tried parenting them the other way from parent to child but cannot use "(.*)" as this will select all of the children in one go not really resolving the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, what you're trying to do here isn't something that can be generally accomplished with regular expressions. Language theory can explain why that is (why such a string cannot be generated by a regular language, and thus why a regular expression isn't "powerful" enough), but I'd likely need *days* to brush up on that topic to be able to explain why.

The simplest way to approach this is probably to iterate over each individual character in the string, and create a new `Section` for each open parenthesis you encounter. You'd also need to keep track of the 'parent' for each node as you go so you can add the appropriate 'children' to it.

In pseudocode, you're looking at something like

```
Integer openParen = '('.charAt(0);
Integer closeParen = ')'.charAt(0);

// Start out by creating the root of the tree/graph you'll be generating
Section root = new Section();
Section parent = root;
Section current;

// getChars() returns a List<Integer>
// Not ideal, but it's what we have
for(Integer character :myString.getChars()){
    if character is an open paren {
       create a new Section (assigning it to 'currentSection')
       add it to the parent's children
       set the 'parent' to be this new Section
    } else if it's a word character {
        add the current character to the current section's string
    } else if it's a close paren {
        set current = parent
        set parent = parent's parent
    }
}
```

Storing the node's parent in your `Section` class would probably make the most sense. You can use the `transient` keyword to prevent that from being serialized when you use `JSON.serialize()`

ex.

```
public class aTest {
    public transient Integer one;
    public Integer two;
}

aTest rec = new aTest();
rec.one = 1;
rec.two = 2;

system.debug(JSON.serialize(rec)); // will print {"two":2}
```

You'll also need to guard against "illegal" strings, things like:

- where the parenthesis are unbalanced `(un(balanced)`
- you encounter a letter after a close paren (without seeing an open paren first) `(an(other(ex))ample)`
- the root of your tree is closed prematurely `(closed(too))(early)`

I'd think that checking that parent == root once the loop finishes and that parent is never null inside the loop would be a good start for that.

Comment: We have code like this in our package, and it uses a stack-based approach, which is basically what you've described here, but formally using a stack seems a bit easier to understand conceptually.